# Uploading AWS Glue Wheel dependencies as a ZIP/TAR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have been wondering what is the best way to upload the library dependencies into AWS Glue.
I would like to copy the dependencies with the wheel all together like it was a `jar`
The AWS documentation is a bit confusing and in some part, they recommend to create a zip/tar with all the wheels, upload it and give it the path as a parameter for `--extra-py-files` (for pythonshell) or `--additional-python-modules` (for spark) depending the version of Glue.
For example, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#aws-glue-programming-python-libraries-zipping).

I found a Snowflake guide that recommends [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/AWS-Glue-Job-in-Python-Shell-using-Wheel-and-Egg-files) as well.

However, I couldn't make it run in AWS Glue with Glue or PythonShell.

Does anyone know what is the best approach to upload dependencies to AWS Glue?

Thank you in advance.